# QWebEnginePage findText всегда false

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Не могу разобраться почему у меня не работает findText в QWebEnginePage, я точно знаю что текст на странице есть, а он пишет false:

```
QWebEnginePage * page2 = new QWebEnginePage;
QUrl tmpUrl;
tmpUrl.setUrl("https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#findText");
page2->load(tmpUrl);

connect(
            page2,
            &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished,
            [page2] (bool ok) {
    if (!ok) {
        qDebug() << "Загрузка документа 2 провалилась.";
        delete page2;
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "Документ 2 загружен, продолжаем.";

    page2->findText(QStringLiteral("findflag"), QWebEnginePage::FindFlags(), [page2](bool found)
    {
        qDebug() << "Поиск в документе 2 : " << found;
    });
    }
);
```

При выполнении пишет:

```
12:40:20: Запускается C:\TSVN\build-HTMLToPDF-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Debug\debug\HTMLToPDF.exe...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
[2936:10440:0331/124024.259:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(642)] Switching to software compositing.
[2936:10440:0331/124024.259:WARNING:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
[2936:10440:0331/124024.259:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(642)] Switching to software compositing.
[2936:10440:0331/124024.259:WARNING:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
[2936:10244:0331/124024.266:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(583)] !GpuDataManagerImpl::GpuProcessStartAllowed()
[2936:10244:0331/124024.266:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(583)] !GpuDataManagerImpl::GpuProcessStartAllowed()
[2936:10440:0331/124024.920:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1", source: https://d33sqmjvzgs8hq.cloudfront.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js.gzip (2)
[2936:10440:0331/124024.920:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1", source: https://d33sqmjvzgs8hq.cloudfront.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js.gzip (2)
Документ 2 загружен, продолжаем.
Поиск в документе 2 :  false
[2936:10440:0331/124037.961:FATAL:render_process_host_impl.cc(887)] Check failed: map_.empty().
```

В чем может быть проблема, может сайт коряво загружается? Но это повторяется и с сохраненными html документами, когда я их загружаю как файл или через setHtml().

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил, сам же и ответ нашел. Слот в котором запускается поиск закрывается быстрее чем успевает отработать поиск, соответственно и page2 уничтожается. Переменную нужно было создавать внутри MainWindow.